# Continuous relay flipping on power strip only

Tags: relay, ups

I have a Belkin WeMo Insight Switch. For those unfamiliar, it is essentially a Wi-Fi enabled 120V relay with current monitoring circuitry for power consumption monitoring.

So, it works great on all outlets in my house, connected to my [APC UPS](http://www.apc.com/shop/us/en/products/APC-Power-Saving-Back-UPS-Pro-700/P-BR700G), etc. But as soon as I try to connect it to [this power strip](http://www.belkin.com/us/BE112230-08-Belkin/p/P-BE112230-08;jsessionid=D729B50558B32B643135351ED292A624/) (I have 3 of them and it happens on all of them) connected to my UPS, it starts continuously flipping on and off. I can hear the relay clicking on and off. I called their support and they say my outlet "isn't compatible" which doesn't help me at all. What could be causing this power strip to do this to the WeMo? Everything else connected to that power strip is fine! Note that the WeMo only flips on and off continuously on this power strip. No other outlet causes this.

Comment: No other power strip does this either?  To me, "outlet" could easily be restricted to "wall socket".

Comment: Is it possible that the wemo does not draw enough initial current to hold the output on?

Comment: AaronD I'll test that this evening @SolarMike what do you mean? Like the delay doesn't draw enough power to stay on? Why would moving to another outlet fix it though?